# Using a page item inside a PL/SQL function body that returns an SQL Query

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to create source code for a list view region that will pick a different table based on the values of page items passed to that page in oracle apex.  Whenever I hard code values for these page items in the PL/SQL function body, the code validates and runs as intended.  But the moment I substitute the hard code for page items it doesn't work.

Here is the code I have that compiles:

```
DECLARE
    list_query varchar2(4000);
    table_name varchar2(400);
    part_id number(6,1);
    table_prefix varchar2(400);
    table_suffix varchar2(400);
    
BEGIN
    table_suffix := 'placeholder value';
    table_prefix := 'placeholder value';
    table_name := table_prefix || table_suffix;
    part_id := 1001;
    list_query := 'select
                      CRITERIA_ID,
                      CRITERIA_NAME,
                      PART_ID,
                      PART_NAME
                   from
                      ' || table_name || '
                   where 
                      PART_ID = ' || part_id || '';
    return(list_query);
END;
```

As long as the place holder values for `table_prefix` and `table_suffix` that are hardcoded combine to make a table name that does exist the code runs and the intended table is displayed in the list view region.  However I need the value of `table_prefix` to populate from a select into statement, while `table_suffix` and `part_id` need to be populated from page items.

So far I haven't been able to get either of these implementations to work.  When trying to populate `table_suffix` page item I receive the following error:

- ORA-20999: Parsing returned query results in "ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! <p>ORA-06550: line 10, column 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist</p>".

```
table_suffix := :P21_PASSED_TABLE;
table_prefix := 'CABLES';
table_name := table_prefix || table_suffix;
part_id := 1001;
```

When I try to populate `part_id` with a page item, I get this error:

- ORA-20999: Parsing returned query results in "ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! <p>ORA-06550: line 12, column 6: ORA-00936: missing expression</p>".

```
table_suffix := '_YES';
table_prefix := 'CABLES';
table_name := table_prefix || table_suffix;
part_id := :P21_PASSED_PART;
```

And when I try to use the select into statement for `table_prefix` , I get this error:

- ORA-01403: no data found

```
table_suffix := '_YES';
SELECT TABLE_NAME into table_prefix FROM ASSEMBLIES_TABLE WHERE ASSEMBLY_ID = :P21_PASSED_ASSEMBLY;
table_name := table_prefix || table_suffix;
part_id := 1001;
```

The variable type that I am trying to put into `table_prefix` is a varchar2(4000) and is pulled directly from a table, `part_id` needs to be populated from a page item that is passed from a different pages page item, that item is a select list and return value (the one being passed onto the current page in question) is a number(6,1).  `:P21_PASSED_ASSEMBLY` is a hidden page item needed in the where clause of the select into statement and is also the return value of a select list on a different page of type number(5,2).  Finally `table_suffix` is pulled from a table and passed to a hidden page item, in the table it is stored as a varchar2(400).

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example. I changed to be on the emp table since I don't have tables with suffixes. The idea is similar. A couple of notes:

- Don't concatenate, you're getting messed up with the quotes and it becomes hard to read. The package [apex_string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeapi/APEX_STRING.html#GUID-CAFD987C-7382-4F0F-8CB9-1D3BD05F054A) has a format function that does the replacement for you.
- Apex will validate the statement when it tries to compile. If the the table name is null at compile time, it's not a valid sql statement and you can't save. So I added `NVL(:P142_SUFFIX,'EMP')`
- debug your code. [apex_debug](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeapi/INFO-Procedure.html#GUID-C8E6E25E-8211-49F8-9110-33F074E68927) is a useful api. Add calls to it in your code, turn debug on and examine the output in the debug report

```
DECLARE
    list_query varchar2(4000);
    table_name varchar2(400);
    part_id number(6,1);
    table_prefix varchar2(400);
    table_suffix varchar2(400);
BEGIN
    table_name := NVL(:P142_TABLE_NAME,'EMP'); --added a default value
    part_id := :P142_EMPNO;
    list_query := 
    q'!select
                      EMPNO,
                      ENAME
                   from
                      %1
                   where 
                      EMPNO = '%0' !';
    list_query := apex_string.format(list_query, part_id,table_name);
    apex_debug.info(p_message =>'Koen Debug: '||list_query);
    return(list_query);
END;
```

Tip for future questions. Strip everything that is not necessary out of your question and reproduce it based on the emp/dept sample schema. That way anyone on this forum can easily reproduce it... and maybe you'll find the answer while writing out your question.