# Oracle Unable to read link attribute value which is remote database from previous page

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have an IG with the following query for PL/SQL returning function body:

```
declare
L_sql varchar2(4000);
l_instead varchar2(100);
begin
l_sql := 'select * from sys.table_links@replace_link'; 
l_instead  := replace(l_sql,'replace_link',:Pl_LINK)   ; 
   return l_sql;
   end;
```

Here P1 Link has its attribute copied from page 2.
Page 2 has a column which is a link and it passes DB_LINK column value to item P1_LINK. However, when i try to validate the above code, it says remote database not found.

But the remote db link is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the apex engine will try to validate the statement when the page is compiled. That is needed to determine a number of attributes of the report (eg nr of columns, data type of columns, etc). When the page is compiled, the value of `:P1_LINK` is null and the sql statement will be invalid.

Solution: change the sql statement so it always returns rows by adding an NVL or a union to a local table. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75803347/using-a-page-item-inside-a-pl-sql-function-body-that-returns-an-sql-query/) is a similar question that makes this clear.

Comment: I tried adding nvl here but it's giving the same error. Am i doing something wrong?  l_instead  := replace(l_sql,'replace_link',nvl(:Pl_LINK,'TEST'))   ;

Comment: I don't know I don't have access to your database. When you run the that code block in sqldeveloper, does it generate valid sql ? Have you tried running it ?

Comment: If that code you posted is the real code it has a bug. The string containing the replaced value is ```l_instead``` but the return value is ```l_sql```. Try ```return l_instead;```

Comment: yes sorry my bad. it works fine now. thank you!